# MacBook Pro HDD won't show in Windows

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp

I've got to send my MBP in for the infamous GPU problem (2011-2013 models) and I would like to back up or at least gain access to my HDD to save some important-ish files.

I've hooked the drive up to my PC, but only the Windows 7 partition shows in My Computer.

When I go to Disk Management, the whole drive shows up as seen in this picture:

[image]

I've got HFSExplorer and that doesn't seem to help. Any ways I can go about gaining access?

Comment: Are you running OS X Yosemite on the mac-side of things, or have you enabled FileVault?

Comment: Im running Yosemite 10.10. Although I honestly cant remember if i've enabled FileVault.

Comment: did you try the migration assistant on your Mac?

Comment: I cant access my account as it keeps crashing due to the GPU problem. I am also trying to access the files on a windows PC as I don't have another mac.

Comment: Does it work in safe mode? (less GPU load)

Comment: Nope. I'll be popping out to get a new Motherboard installed tomorrow. I just don't want to risk loosing data.

Answer (score 1):

Yosemite converts your drive to Core Storage, which makes most Windows utilities that used to be able to read Mac drives, unable to do so. I'd suggest making an image of the drive. I'm not terribly familiar with Windows disk imaging software, but it looks like [DAEMON Tools](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite) will get the job done. There's a "Lite" version that claims to be able to do it.

Comment: So if I make an image of my drive what would I do with that then? It's been a long time. 

The main problem that I may face is that I don't have 700gb free space.

Comment: Basically, you'd save it for later so you can restore it when you get your drive back. Although without enough room, I suppose this would be difficult... You can try the 5-day MacDrive trial from http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/. If FileVault isn't enabled, it will be able to read your disk, and let you retrieve your documents.

Comment: I'll give that a go in a bit.

Comment: It looks like a nope to me. I guess I have file vault enabled. Is there any way to disable firevault without logging? I have the passwords etc, just when it loads up the user account it crashes.

Comment: There is no software that I know of that can decrypt a FileVault-encrypted disk on Windows. This is a real predicament...